# If $a^3-3a^2 + 5a + 11 = 0$ and $b^3 - 3b^2 +5b-17=0$. Find $a+b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers such that $a^3-3a^2 + 5a + 11 = 0$ and $b^3 - 3b^2 +5b-17=0$. Find $a + b$.

***First attempt***: When we add the equations we can spot some ($a+b$) terms but there are $ab$ terms too. It leads to no where.

***Second attempt:***  Let $p(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x$, then $p(a) = -11$ and $p(b) = 17$, therefore $p(a) + p(b) = 6$. But what to do next ?

Comment: you can try that a^3-3a^2+5a+9+2 = (a-1)(a^2-4a+9)+2

Comment: $0=(a^3-3a^2 + 5a + 11)+(b^3 - 3b^2 +5b-17)=(a + b - 2) (a^2 - a b - a + b^2 - b + 3)$. Consider the discriminant of the quadratic term with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $a+b=x$ and substitute $b=x-a$ in the second equation and add the first equation. Then one obtains
$$
(3a^2 - 3ax + x^2 - x + 3)(x - 2)=0
$$
If $x=2$, then $a+b=2$. The second factor yields no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $a=x+1$ and $b=y+1$ to get

$$x^3+2x=-14$$
$$y^3+2y=14$$

Then add the equations

$$x^3+y^3 + 2x+2y = 0$$

Which factors

$$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)+2(x+y)=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2+2)=0$$

So one solution is $x+y = (a-1)+(b-1) = 0$ so $a+b=2$.

Comment: $$x^3+y^3 + 2x+2y = 0$$ Why do you think, "one solution is  ". Does this imply other possible solutions?

Comment: @User  There aren't any other (real) solutions, but I haven't argued that.  A quick calculus check shows the minimum value of the other factor to be greater than zero.

Comment: Did you mean "only solution is" instead of "one solution is"? There is a small typo in your equation. Check my first comment

Comment: @User No, I just left that bit for the OP.